# How many ways can you color a regular tetrahedron with 3 colors

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am trying to solve a problem from brilliant.org and drawing a complete blank. Given that you have 3 colors of paint and a regular tetrahedron, you want to paint all sides one and only one color, and rotations of the tetrahedron are considered equivalent, how many ways are there to paint all sides of the tetrahedron?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is not isolated. The source was mentioned.

Comment: "...you want to paint all sides one and only one color..."  I think that you mean ...paint **each** side one and only one color.

Answer (score 2):

If you use only one colour there are $3$ ways to paint the tetrahedron. If you use two, there are $3$ ways to pick the colours and $3$ ways to assign colours up to rotation (given any number of faces painted colour A, there is only one way up to rotation to actually paint those faces).

If you use three, one colour must be used twice – $3$ ways to pick it – and there is only one way to paint the other faces with the two remaining colours up to rotations.

Hence the answer is $3+3×3+3=15$. (This can also be derived from Burnside's lemma: identity + $8$ rotations on vertex + $3$ rotations on edge gives $\frac{3^4+8\cdot3^2+3\cdot3^2}{12}=15$.)